# Computer vision library to guess the relative positions/angles of two 360-degree photos?

Tags: computer-vision

Is there a software library out there that can assist in analysing pairs of 360 degrees equirectangular photos and finding their relative positions and rotation?

For example, 3 photos taken with a 360 camera in the same bedroom, one or two meters apart. The software takes the 3 files as inputs and, for each pair of photos, using image processing/pattern recognition, output the x,y,z distance between them and angles.

The idea is to have a sort of graph of how all the photos are related spatially to each other.

I guess a commercial product like matterport use something like that internally (plus a lot of other things). Anyway, no interest in building a full 3d model of the space, just the relative positioning. thanks

Comment: Don't know of a complete algorithm but [scattering](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/75636/50076) would extract useful features.

Comment: Please don’t cross-post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69169818/computer-vision-algorithm-library-to-guess-the-relative-positions-angles-of-two