# What are the purposes of color extraction using k-means clustering?

Tags: image-processing, quantization, k-means

Using K-means clustering it is possible to reduce the amount of colors in an image. What are the purposes of using this method for extracting colors from an image?

Comment: one purpose _is_ palette generation. please review [ask] and present your research.

Comment: Note that there are other methods much more suitable than k-means for finding a reduced palette.

Answer (score 1):

There are some use cases:

- Palette Generation
  The centroids becomes a color in the palette.
- Segmentation
  If you add the location of the pixels as a feature you can use the K-Means as segmentation tool as done in Super Pixels (See [Rectangle Segments of Image (Rectangle Super Pixels) per Pixel](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/81880) and [Locate Non Homogenous Areas in an Image](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/75536)).